# How to do something when user profile rendereing?

Tags: php, buddypress

Im new with worpress.
I have a site wp+buddypress. Now i want get a fields value in user profile and do something depend by this field value. I can get this value useing:

```
$class = xprofile_get_field_data( ‘Field_Name’, $user_id );
```

But i can't found place where i gonna put my code.
What method i need to modify, or maybe exist hook what i can use to create separate plugin?

`UPDATE Some code`

```
<?php
function remove_xprofile_links() {  
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $field = xprofile_get_field_data(3, $user_id);

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $field . "' );</script>";
}
add_action( 'bp_init', 'remove_xprofile_links' );
```

?>

I put some code in `bp-custom.php`. Now i know a field value. But still dont know how to hide fields. Any advises?

Comment: I would say it depend on what you want to do :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld i want to hide profile fields depend this field value.

Comment: The easiest way I think would be putting a function inside functions.php (preferably in a child theme) and calling that function from the template that are used.

Comment: I update question please look at it.

Comment: Where do you want to hide fields?  In the profile loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I give it a try...

```
<?php function remove_xprofile_links() {  
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $field = xprofile_get_field_data(3, $user_id);

    $class = 'normal-profile';
    if ($field == '{whatever}') {
        $class ='hidden-profile';
    }

    $html = '<div class="' .$class . '">' . $field . '</div>';
    echo $html;
   ?>
```

And in css you should have

```
.hidden-profile {display:none;}
```